# Running "strpos" on each array element

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find out if a string exists within an array value, but isn't necessarily the actual array value.

```
$array = array(
       0 => 'blue', 
       1 => 'red', 
       2 => 'green', 
       3 => 'red'
);

$key = xxxxxx('gr', $array); // $key = 2;
```

Is there a built in way to do this with PHP

Comment: What do you mean with $key = 2? Do you want to find a certain value or a certain key?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [**preg_grep**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) for this purpose

```
<?php
$array = array(
       0 => 'blue', 
       1 => 'red', 
       2 => 'green', 
       3 => 'red'
);

//$key = xxxxxx('gr', $array); // $key = 2;
$result=preg_grep("/^gr.*/", $array);
print_r($result);
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/YYGFye7L)

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could, loooong time since I remembered PHP had a `preg_grep()` function!

Comment: I'm trying `preg_grep("/^\/scripts\/GMC\/PNetT\-5\.1\-SP1\/PNetT.*/", exec('ps -ef | grep GMC', $output));` but it's not finding the result when I know the result exists.... am I escaping this properly?

Comment: @Webnet, `exec` doesn't return the array. Use two separate statements, one to call `exec` and the other the call `preg_grep(..., $output)`. Or skip `preg_grep` entirely and just put that regular expression in your `grep` command directly.

Comment: Psh - you're right, I only did that so you could see what I was executing.  I'm actually passing `$output` to the preg_grep, but it's not matching.  Is it escaped correctly?

Comment: Yes, but it's too restrictive. The `^` at the start of the expression says the substring must *start* some line of the program output, but that's not where `ps` puts the command line. Remove the `^` from the start and the `.*` from the end (which is redundant). Also, the `-` characters don't need to be escaped; they're not usually special. (Even in `[...]`, they don't need escaping if you put them in the right place.)

Comment: The demo doesn't function anymore

Answer (score 2):

Function: [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is  what you want. It will only preserve the items in the resulting array when the specified function return true for them.

```
// return true if "gr"  found in $elem
// for this value
function isGr($key, $elem)
{
    if (strpos($elem, "gr") === FALSE)
    {
         return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
         return TRUE;
    }
}

$grElems = array_filter($array, "isGr");
print_r($grElems);
```

results in:

```
array(
    2=>'green'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `xxxxxx` would be `array_map`. But alas, you cannot use `strpos` as plain callback here. To pass the actual search parameter, you need to define a custom or anonymous function-

And to get what you want, you need more wrapping still:

```
 $key = key(
          array_filter(
             array_map(
                function($s){return strpos($s, "gr");},
                $array
             ),
          "is_int")
        );
```

This gives you the searched index `2` however.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function but since `preg_*` functions support arrays as arguments this should work:

```
$keys = preg_filter('~gr~', '$0', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

---

what about foreach ?

```
function xxxxxx($str, $array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     if (strpos($value, $str) !== false) {
        return $key;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This method worked perfect for what I was after. I altered it slightly so I can feed single and multiple needles.

    function find($haystack, $needles) {
        $needle = array_map('trim', explode(",", $needles));
            foreach ($needle as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos($value, $haystack) !== false) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }

Then I call something like find($page, "home, about");

Answer (score 0):

use

> array_walk with strpos

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: And the arguments to strpos go where?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check each item, then return the index if it does.

```
function substr_in_array($array, $substr) {
    foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
        if (strrpos($item, $substr)!===FALSE && $item != $substr) {
            return $index;
        }
    }
}
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It checks using foreach every array element using strpos.

```
<?php
$array = array(
       0 => 'blue', 
       1 => 'red', 
       2 => 'green', 
       3 => 'red'
);
$search='aaa';
function arraysearch($array,$search){
foreach ($array as $element){
if(strpos($element,$search)!==FALSE){
return TRUE;
}
}
return FALSE;
}
echo arraysearch($array,$search);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3 you can do it in one command using array_filter and an anonymous function:

```
$keys = array_filter($array, function($var){ return strpos($var, 'gr') !== false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using PHP >= 5.3.0, you could use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) to filter that array with [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter).

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'blue', 
    1 => 'red', 
    2 => 'green', 
    3 => 'red'
);

$search = 'gr';

$key = array_filter($array, function($element) use($search) {
    return strpos($element,$search) !== FALSE;
});
```

This is an improved version of `Shay Ben Moshe` response.